# No javax in Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Creating "hello world" Servlet application in Eclipse 2020-09 JEE that runs in Ubuntu machine according to [manual](https://medium.com/@prashant.srivastava7744/how-to-create-hello-world-servlet-example-using-eclipse-ide-with-tomcat-7-39fdbdc21573) . Java version 15.

Looks like project can't find javax library. Why? How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Those should be coming from your server (it needs them as well). Your project should be targeting a Tomcat 9 server if you followed those directions. Is it not?

Comment: I have problems by setting Tomcat server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123098/tomcat-installation-and-configuration-for-eclipse-dynamic-web-project

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can resolve this by not importing "Javax" ,instead, you have to import "Jakarta" as tomcat having

```
import jakarta.srevelet.
jakarta.servelet
```