# Tomcat installation and configuration for Eclipse dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, tomcat, eclipse-jee

I have installed Tomcat 9 by using standard way in my Ubuntu 20:

```
sudo apt install tomcat9 tomcat9-admin
```

But this installation not defines `CATALINA_HOME` value.

`echo $CATALINA_HOME` brings nothing. Why? What is right location for `CATALINA_HOME`?

Conent of `/var/lib/tomcat9` :
conf  lib  logs  policy  webapps  work

Conent of `/etc/tomcat9` :
conf  lib  logs  policy  webapps  work

My Eclipse JEE Tomcat server runtime environment configuration complains with message

```
Unknown version of Tomcat was specified.
```

How to fix that problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an installed copy. The locations of files needed to properly launch Tomcat from Eclipse and actually control the process could have been relocated to *who knows where*. Download the tar/zip file from tomcat.eclipse.org, and use that instead.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F

Answer (score 0):

When you install by command

```
sudo apt install tomcat9 tomcat9-admin
```

Tomcat become a services inside operating system. Don't use this way in development.

Download Apache Tomcat, unzip, then point to its directory / declare path of Tomcat in Eclipse IDE. Tip: Must check permission some files, allow it read, write inside Tomcat.